# Merge multiple files from server folder into one

Tags: python

I have tried to merge some files in server folder into a new file, saving under same server folder.

In my below script, I keep receiving unexpected indent error.  I would like to seek some expert guidance.

```
import pandas as pd    # import need to be in lower case
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

from openpyxl.workbook import workbook #save to excel doc
```

#>>> 1.1 Define common file path and filename
path= '\hbap.adroot.abb\HK\Finance\00210602\AMH_A2R\1KY\Drv Reengine\Python\'

#>>> 1.2 Define list of files
filenames = [path+'100_6.xlsx', path+'101_6.xlsx']

```
# Open file3 in write mode 
  with Open(r path+'file3.xlsx','w') as outfile: 

# Iterate through list 
for names in filenames: 

# Open each file in read mode 
    with open(names) as infile: 

# read the data from file1 and 
# file2 and write it in file3 
  outfile.write(infile.read()) 

        # Add '\n' to enter data of file2 
        # from next line 
     outfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: why `with Open(r path+'file3.xlsx','w') as outfile:` line indented?

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at proposed solution.

In this case I take all files present in /sql directory, read all of them one by one and append the result to the output file.

```
import os

files_list = list()
output = r"E:\Downloads\output.txt"
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(r'E:\Downloads\sql'):
    files_list += [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]

for file in files_list:
    fin = open(file, "rt")
    data = fin.read()
    fin.close()
    fin = open(output, "a+")
    fin.write(data)
    fin.write("\n ---------- \n")
    fin.close()
```

Also I might suggest that you are dealing with .xlsx files which is a bit different topic and merging excel files should be treated in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Having a correct indentation is important in python as the interpreter uses it to read the code.
This has an ordered indent level:

```
# Open file3 in write mode 
with Open(r path+'file3.xlsx','w') as outfile: 
    # Iterate through list 
    for names in filenames: 
        # Open each file in read mode 
        with open(names) as infile: 
            # read the data from file1 and 
            # file2 and write it in file3 
            outfile.write(infile.read()) 
            # Add '\n' to enter data of file2 
            # from next line 
            outfile.write("\n")
```